# Why do I need "a" in "a mere 5 percent"?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Examples (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mere)

- Sixty per cent of teachers are women, but a mere 5 percent of women are heads and deputies.
- Tickets are a mere £7.50 at the door.
- Its online business increased sales by a mere 1 per cent.

**Question**

Why do I need "a" because I think "percent" is uncountable?

Comment: The informal 'Tickets are a whopping £75.00 at the door' shows a similar structure. Perhaps the availability of 'He's a mere youth' alongside 'He's merely a youth' has encouraged the 'a mere [quantity]' string, ''merely 10 dollars / kilos / degrees / miles ...' not being too remarkable. 'Whoppingly £75.00' is, however, _not_ unremarkable.

Comment: It's true that *percent* is uncountable, but it's preceded by *mere*, an adjective. In many cases (not all) if an adjective is used with an uncountable noun, then an article becomes required where it wouldn't otherwise be.

Answer (score -1):

The analysis of the sentence *"... a mere 5 percent of women are heads"* is not obvious.

**Five**[1] is

(i) a noun: It expresses the written number "5" (or "V") and the abstract quantity that is one more than four. Consider,

“You have written my telephone number wrongly – You need **three fives**, not **two fives**, and **the six** should be **an eight**.”

(ii) an adjective "Two sisters" or an absolute adjective acting as a noun/pronoun: A: "How many sister do you have?"
B: "I have two"' "I have two of them".

**Mere** modifies "5"

**Percent** is an adjectival modifier which means “in one hundred” – it is not a noun: “Five percent” = Five in one hundred.

*"... a mere 5 in one hundred of women are heads"* Has the same construction as

A mere two in a thousand [people] understand this.

[1] OED
**A. adj.**

1 a. With modified noun expressed.

1845   B. Disraeli Sybil II. iv. v. 197   The national petition [...] to take into consideration the five points

**B. n.**

1. a. The abstract number five.

1876   C. P. Mason Eng. Gram. (ed. 21) §62 (note)    We say ‘twice five is ten’.

b. The figure (5) or letter (V) denoting this number.

2. A set of five things.

   a. Cards and Dominos. A card or domino marked with five pips.

?1870   F. Hardy & J. R. Ware Mod. Hoyle 81   Suppose your hand consists of a four, five, and six of spades.

Comment: '5' is not seen to be an adjective by any modern grammarians. Most consider numerals a different word-class even from determiners. But both quantifiers (which _are_ determiners) and numerals / equivalents take 'a mere' as premodifiers: 'He went out with two thousand but returned with a mere hundred and twenty-two' / 'a mere half-dozen / 22% / handful' [+ various completers; 'of them' but 'men/of men']. 'Merely' behaves differently; 'merely a half-dozen'; 'merely 72 of them', 'merely 22% of them'; 'merely a handful of them'.